# SharePoint 2016 On Premises - "Share Everything in this Folder even with unique permissions"

Tags: security, share, 2016

On Office 365 SharePoint there is the option to add another group to a Document Library and then there is a tick box for "Share Everything in this Folder even with unique permissions".

Does anyone know if this feature is going to be in SharePoint 2016 ON PREMISES.  If you do can you provide a screen shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just upgraded my SharePoint Server 2016 Beta 2 to Release Candidate, and so far this option isn't available.

In Office 365, you have this option:

[image]

Trying to do the same in SharePoint Server 2016 RC, you get the message that you need to disable a feature first:

[image]

Said and done, lets disable the feature:

[image]

Now we have our Sharing option, but still not "Share everything in this folder, even items with unique permissions".

[image]

But this may come when the product is released to the public, or when SP1 is available, or later. But today, this feature is non-existing.